# Converting Polar Equation to Cartesian Equation: general form solution

Tags: polar-coordinates

I'm trying to find the Cartesian equivalent of the general equation
$$r=a\cos(q\theta) + c; q\in\mathbb Q, a\gt c \in\mathbb R$$
if it exists. My memory of calc is a bit hazy, and I haven't been able to break this up using any of the trig identities that I remember, or could find online. I've also tried using Laplace transforms for fixed $a, c, q$. However, this resulted in an expression containing complex exponentials. For example
$$r(\theta)=\cos\left(\frac 57\theta\right) + 2=\frac 1 {98}\left[e^{-5i\theta}+e^{5i\theta}\right] + 2$$
This strategy wasn't very fruitful as I have almost no background in complex math, and have no idea how to handle those exponential terms.

I'm very curious to know weather there's a general cartesian solution corresponding to this type of polar equation. I'd also be exceedingly grateful for a worked example using set constants, or recommendations for reading material that might help me to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this as $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=a\cos\left(q\arctan(\frac yx)\right)+c$$

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. Funny how a single simple rule can simplify a problem so drastically. Thanks a million!

Comment: You're welcome ...

Answer (score 0):

If you restricted the solution set to $q$ being an integer, then you could make use of this identity:
$$
\cos(q\theta)=\sum_{k=0}^q\cos^k(\theta)\sin^{q-k}(\theta)\cos\left(\frac{(q-k)\pi}{2}\right)
$$
Then using:
$$\begin{align}
r&=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\\
\cos(\theta)&=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\
\sin(\theta)&=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\end{align}$$
You end up with:
$$
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=a\left(\sum_{k=0}^q\frac{x^ky^{q-k}}{(x^2+y^2)^\frac{q}{2}}\cos\left(\frac{(q-k)\pi}{2}\right)\right)+c
$$
(assuming I haven't made any errors in my calculations)

Comment: That's a great suggestion, and very thorough! Unfortunately I need q to be a rational because of the [pattern](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+r%3Dcos+%285*theta%2F7%29%2B2) that this restriction produces. Integers generate patterns which are equally interesting, but don't fit my criteria.

Comment: I believe the answer given by @DavidQuinn below is simpler and doesn't suffer from the restrictions that I imposed above. He has used the fact that:$$\tan(\theta)=\frac{y}{x}$$